# How to adjust amplitude of flash light on android mobile?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using Note 3 (rooted) and I used Adjustable Torch [ROOT] - Android Apps on Google Play to adjust lighting power of flash light. Can you help me answer some below questions:

1. How to know value of brightness of flash on default camera (some
   people said that I can find it in file on android system folder, but
   I cannot find)
2. When I use Adjustable Torch to change value of flash, how to know value of brightness.

My purpose is to compare 2 values and find the suitable value of brightness (lower is better) to calculate heart rate using camera. 
Thank you!

Comment: Can you check /sys/class/leds/torch-light/brightness file exists on your device?

Comment: Thanks, I accessed to torch folder and I can change brightness of flash via Adjustable Torch but I cannot turn on/off flash and audjust without Adjustable Torch. How do I know the value of default camera and how to adjust it?